# linux command "android" : equivalent in Windows?

Tags: android, windows, ant, command-line

i'm use to linux environment but at the moment i have to develop an android app under a windows environment.

So i need to run the "android" command ( **android.bat** ) in the windows prompt ( located in $ANDROID_HOME/tools/ ) in order to add ant script and do other stuffs.

the thing is that this launches me the Android SDK Manager, instead of giving me command line answer lie : "project updated"... So my question is :

How do i run the android command under Windows ?? to run things such as :

**android update project --path**

Maybe i'm not running the right bat file ? I did many search over the internet, without finding any answers.

I managed to make work Ant perfectly though, with the "**ant.bat**" that is located in the ant directory

EDIT :

Problem solved.

instead of typing :

**android** update project --path XXX

in the $ANDROID_HOME/tools/ directory, which would open me the SDK Manager, i had to do :

**android.bat** update project --path XXX

Answer (score 1):

You can make it even easier by setting the ANDROID_HOME environment variable to the path to the sdk directory and then adding the paths for tools and platform-tools to your system PATH environment variable.

Then you can run the command **android** instead of android.bat from the command line, as you are used to, without having to type the full path or change to the sdk directory.

There are [instructions for setting Windows environment variables here](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm).

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered same problem in Windows. I did it this way and it works for me .

```
   $ $ANDROID_SDK/sdk/tools/android.bat update project -p .
     Updated local.properties
     Updated file C:\ndk\android-ndk-r9b\samples\hello-jni\proguard-project.txt
     It seems that there are sub-projects. If you want to update them
     please use the --subprojects parameter
```

Here first used "cd" command to go the ndk project directory that is way I used "."(dot) for path(-p)

```
$ANDROID_SDK/sdk/tools/android.bat update project -p .
```